# How to extract certificate from SAML Identity provider Metadata

Tags: certificate, websphere, metadata, saml

I am using websphere's AdminTask.importSAMLIdpMetadata() function to import SAML IdP metadata into my server.

AdminTask.importSAMLIdpMetadata('-idpId 1 -ssoId 1 -idpMetadataFileName ' + idpMetaDataFile + ' -signingCertAlias ' + idpCertificateAlias   + securityDomainParam);

It is working fine.

Problem is that if same certificates is already imported under some other alias then, it does not create new alias for same certificate.

To achieve this I need to write custom logic that will do all tasks of importSAMLIdpMetadata() and in always create alias

My questions:

1. How to extract certificate from IdP Metadata. ( In Java, Jython or Ant )
2. How to check if this certificate is already present in Websphere "signer certificates". ( In Java, Jython or Ant )

Answer (score 0):

I tried doing above task myself
1)  certificate can be extracted from IdP Metadata in java, like normal XML pasring and reading

2) To check if certificate is already present in Websphere "signer certificates" :-
Use jython to get all the certificates

AdminTask.listSignerCertificates('[-keyStoreName NodeDefaultTrustStore -keyStoreScope (cell):cell_name:(node):node_name  ]')

It will give you a big string with each key value pair in square brackets []

Pass it to java and parse it as required.